# How to implement Domain Verification using TXT Records in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can I do domain verification via ASP.NET and C#?

Basically, I want to verify/check TXT records on a domain if it's supporting our own mail web server.
I have checked with http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx but this is not working for all domains.

We have to implement this feature same as SparkPost:
https://www.sparkpost.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-sparkpost/#sending-domain-step-2-verifying-domain-ownership